# windows api for ble ibeacon?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

As my knowing, the Bluetooth low energy (BLE) is supported in(above) Windows 8.

But I do not have any cue about how to code a iBeacon scanner in Windows.

Is there are any example or reference mentioning about it?

That behavior is like most iBeacon detectors/scanners app in Android/iOS.

Thank your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Windows currently doesn't support scanning or acting as iBeacon(s) nativly. However, you have some options:

- Use a VM that runs linux with BlueZ stack
- Use a RaspberryPI as 'detector' that hosts a WebAPI interface to your Windows machine
- Change the driver of you Bluetooth 4.0 dongle to libusb and write your own HCI layer + BLE stack, for working with iBeacons only a very small portion of the stack is needed (I've done it before and it works perfectly)
- Wait for [Windows 10](http://wmpoweruser.com/windows-10-will-support-ibeacon-technology/)