# iBeacon BLE Bluetooth 4.0 Windows 7

Tags: ibeacon

How can I create an iBeacon on a windows 7 PC with Smart Bluetooth 4.0 integrated with the Wi-Fi, I.e not a separate dongle. I'd rather not look at other OS's as the device also has to run an Adobe air application at the same time.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: possible duplicate of [windows api for ble ibeacon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909812/windows-api-for-ble-ibeacon)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you cannot natively make a Bluetooth LE-equipped Windows 7/8/8.1 computer broadcast as an iBeacon.  The operating system is limited in its BLE support to allowing third party apps to work with a limited number of BLE profiles.  More details are available here in this question about Windows phone, but the info also applies to the desktop Windows OS:

[iBeacon support for Windows Phone devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229765/ibeacon-support-for-windows-phone-devices). Support is expected to be added in Windows 10 in late 2015.

Until then, your options are limited to a Linux VM or to a hardware dongle with native iBeacon support.

Answer (score 0):

As David pointed out, there is no API available for working with iBeacons until [Windows 10](http://wmpoweruser.com/windows-10-will-support-ibeacon-technology/).

If you don't need any other Bluetooth connectivity, you can replace the Bluetooth driver with a libusb driver and use your own Bluetooth stack which adds support for iBeacon. You can check out open-source libraries like BlueZ and btstack and make the HCI layer work. On top of that you can implement/port the BLE advertisement and discovery HCI commands and you have all you need for working with iBeacons.